# Proof/Explanation for why the Hamiltonian operator's eigenvalues are the permitted energy values?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, operators, hamiltonian, eigenvalue

I'm looking for a proof as to why the Hamiltonian operator's eigenvalues in quantum mechanics are the permitted energies of a quantum particle. I am looking for an intuitive explanation as well as a mathematical proof, preferably in the form of spinor notation.

Comment: Spinor notation??

Comment: Why do you ask this for the Hamiltonian and not any other observable (such as position, momentum, angular momentum etc.)?

Comment: Why do you think it applies only to fermions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not completely correct to say that the Hamiltonian operator's eigenvalues in quantum mechanics are the permitted energies of a quantum particle. It would be better to say that they are the permitted energies of stationary states. Said in another way, only energies corresponding to the eigenvalues may correspond to time-independent probability distributions and currents. Other energies are allowed but can only correspond to scattering states.

The mathematical proof is trivial: only the eigenstates correspond to a simple time dependence like $e^{-I E_n t/\hbar}$, and then to a time-independent $|\psi|^2$ (if you consider it important, $\psi$ can be a spinor).

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know this is a postulate of quantum mechanics (e.g Griffiths Introduction to Quantum Mechanics 3rd ed., Chapter 3) and the only proof of the postulate is experimental (e.g Stern-Gerlach experiment, the mass of modern AMO spectroscopy literature, amongst others…). We use this theory to make various predictions and a lot of the time they turn out to be accurate, this is as much proof as we can get.

The only explanation I can provide is that operators corresponding to observable in quantum mechanics are required to be hermitian and thus (via the [spectral theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem)) have all real eigenvalues. This is a requirement we need because we don’t want the theory to predict unphysical energies, positions, etc.